# How to modify a font on a hyperlink on a page on SPD 2010 without having to save it to the CSS as it keeps asking?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How do you modify the font on a page without having to save it to the core.CSS as it keeps prompting? I don't want to affect anyone else's pages and don't want the core.css overwritten by another user thus making me lose my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add content Editor webpart on the page and add your custom css.
It will not affect other pages on the site.